# -E or - x required when input is from standard input

Tags: ios, xcode6, armv7

I have created a Static Library for one of my project and now I am adding this library to my another project. Everything seems to work well but when I build I get the following error

> [Error] -E or - x required when input is from standard input

I am attaching a snapshot of error log also.

[image: Error Log]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got a solitary `-` in your `clang` command line, which signifies that the source file is to be read via stdin. This probably crept in via a project setting - go through your settings and check for a stray `-`.

Comment: anywhere in my project setting or some particular place like linker flags or so? thanks for quick response :)

Comment: I would start with linker settings, but it could be almost anywhere.